# Chrome clean-up batch script

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch

I wrote a batch script that should automatically delete sensitive data but NOT nuke away everything.

What my (shortened) script currently looks like

```
set ChromeDir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data

attrib +R +H +S "%ChromeDir%\Default\*Bookmarks*"
attrib +R +H +S "%ChromeDir%\Default\*Preferences*"
attrib +R +H +S "%ChromeDir%\Default\Extensions\*" /S /D
del /q /s "%ChromeDir%"
attrib -R -H -S "%ChromeDir%\Default\*Bookmarks*"
attrib -R -H -S "%ChromeDir%\Default\*Preferences*"
attrib -R -H -S "%ChromeDir%\Default\Extensions\*" /S /D
```

What my script should do

```
Delete everything except bookmarks, preferences and extensions
```

What my script does

```
Delete everything except bookmarks and extensions
```

The preferences that I want to save (default download path, default home page, bookmarks always visible etc.. everything you find under the (extended) settings) are somehow not in the Preferences file.

But where are they? How can I improve the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those settings are in next text files that contain `JSON` markup (*JavaScript Object Notation* format):

```
Bookmarks
Preferences
Secure Preferences
TransportSecurity
```

Browsing history with sensitive data are stored in next files (some of these files are used to be *locked* when Google Chrome browser is active, and could stay *locked* even if *Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed* switch is *on* in [settings](http://chrome://settings/)):

`SQLite` databases (and related `*-journal` files):

```
Cookies
Extension Cookies
Favicons
History
Login Data
Network Action Predictor
Origin Bound Certs
QuotaManager
Shortcuts
Top Sites
Web Data
```

Files in unknown format with `SNSS` file signature, cf. [src/chrome/browser/sessions/session_backend.cc](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/sessions/session_backend.cc?view=markup)

```
Current Session
Current Tabs
Last Session
Last Tabs
```

Files in unknown format:

```
Visited Links
History Provider Cache
```

The `README` file contains next caveat: *Google Chrome settings and storage represent user-selected preferences and information and MUST not be extracted, overwritten or modified except through Google Chrome defined APIs.*

Comment: That caveat is no problem for me since I don't want to modify it. I just want to exclude the right file from deletion.

Comment: @josefZ - Could the SQLite or JSON files be edited manually now? Or do some Secure Hashes also come in the way?

Answer (score 0):

These settings are in the `Preferences` file, in JSON format.

Location of this configuration file is
Linux : `/USER_HOME_FOLDER/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`
Windows : `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

For example, the default download path looks like that :

```
"download": {
      "default_directory": "CURRENT_PATH_OF_YOUR_DOWNLOAD_FOLDER",
      "directory_upgrade": true,
      "extensions_to_open": "",
      "prompt_for_download": false
 },
```

The preference key for default download directory may seem to have disappeared from that file,
because Chrome seems to not include it in the file if its value is Chrome's default value.

There are tools for manipulating JSON files in the language of your choice :

[Parsing JSON File Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939250/parsing-json-file-java) and [JSON Manipulation in Java – Examples](http://crunchify.com/json-manipulation-in-java-examples/)
[C++ : JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)
[Intro to manipulating JSON file from PERL scripts](http://www.attunity.com/forums/replicate-console/intro-manipulating-json-file-perl-scripts-2944.html)

The above are just some examples I found at random (not necessarily the best references).